# nodejs pipe http response to koa res

Tags: node.js, http, koa

I am using koa ,
How can I send user's request to another server when some condition meet , then got the response from the server and send it to the user , as if I am a proxy server. 
I use the http.request and got the res , now How can I pipe the res to the user's socket , just like a original http server `res.pipe(response)`

For example

```
var options = {
      host: "blog.suconghou.cn",
      port: 80,
      encoding: null,
      path: "http://blog.suconghou.cn",
      headers: {
        Host: "blog.suconghou.cn"
      }
    };

    http.request(options, function(res)
    {
        res.pipe(process.stdout);
        console.log(res.body,typeof res);
        ctx.body=res; // ctx is this in app.use
    }).end();
```

it not work , i don't know how to pipe it to the koa's response

Comment: idea: wrap http.request in a function that returns a promise with `resolve(res)`. from the route, try `ctx.body = yield makeRequest(...)`. one issue with your code is that your koa handler returns before the request callback is finished. you need to wait for it.

Comment: @danneu ok, I know , but how can I use the pipe such as https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/lib/application.js#L227 , so that I need not do a lot about the headers

Answer (score -2):

`request` library support streams, using it you can do as following.

```
let request = require('request');

function *mid() {
    let options = {
        host: "blog.suconghou.cn",
        port: 80,
        encoding: null,
        path: "http://blog.suconghou.cn",
        headers: {
            Host: "blog.suconghou.cn"
        }
    };

    this.req.pipe(request(options))
            .pipe(this);
            .once('error', console.log);
}
```